# How to set the proxy configuration in objective c

Tags: objective-c, macos, proxy, network-programming

I am a newbie to objective c. I am developing a mac application which include several network communication. Usually I am posting data to our data center using direct internet connection. I would like to do the same using local proxy connection. Can I do this using NSURLConnection?
if not can you please let me know the correct method to connect send and receive data using proxy connection?

Answer (score 1):

`NSURLConnection` will automatically use the system settings for the proxy. You don't have to do anything to enable that.

Comment: Hi Ken Thanks for you response. I have to set individually  for my application.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using ASIHTTP framework.

You can download the framework from below URL.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

### Sample code to post data via proxy.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:fullURL];


    [request setProxyHost:proxyIP];

    [request setProxyPort:proxyPort];

    [request setProxyUsername:proxyUserName];

    [request setProxyPassword:.proxyPassword];

    [request appendPostData:theBodyData];

    [request startSynchronous];
```